# Laravel: having trouble installing laravel-ffmpeg package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm a JS developer doing some Laravel and I'm having trouble using a package.  I am trying to use a ffmpeg wrapper ( https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg ) and I went through the instructions to install it via composer and added it to config/app.php in the aliases and providers section as details.

At the top of my Users file, I have `use Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpegFacade;` below the others.

I am then using it my code as follows in a function:

```
public function createThumb($url, $product) 
{
        $media = FFMpeg::open($url);
        $thumb = $media->getFrameFromString('00:00:05.00');
        $originalWidth = $thumb->width();
        $originalHeight =$thumb->height();
        $filename = "test";
}
```

I keep getting an error `Error: Class 'App\UserProfile\FFMpeg` not found referencing the line where I call it.  I'm not sure what I am missing to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in config->app.php

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'FFMpeg' => Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpegFacade::class
    ...
];
```

And give the reference of class in file where you have to use this class like below.

```
use FFMpeg;
```